# Does the 1:1 ratio of wise virgins to foolish ones have any significance?

Tags: catholicism, kingdom-of-god, judgement

We see in Mtt 25:1-13 Jesus presenting the Parable of Ten Virgins. Of the ten, five are wise , anticipate delay in arrival of the groom, and stock enough oil to last through the ceremony. Five are foolish and are not prepared for unanticipated events. The ratio of wise and foolish virgins is one to one. Elsewhere, Jesus says that a few out of the many invited, are chosen for the reward of eternal life ( Mtt 22:14). My question is : According to Catholic scholars, does the ratio of wise virgins to foolish ones have any significance ?

Comment: Five is the number of pilgrimage through adversity (see Benjamin and portions). So both sets of virgins sojourned in the present world as pilgrims, but one group were foolish and misunderstood how a lamp works (they took no oil) thinking that a dry wick would burn on its own. The other group understood that the apparatus of lamp (a figure of the doctrine of the gospel) is useless without oil, the supply of the Spirit. For in Him (who is Word) is Life. But without His _Person_ the bare doctrine is mere information . . . .  and there will be no marriage union. Up-voted +1.

Comment: Thanks, Nigel. I would differ on one of your points. The foolish virgins did keep some oil in the lamp, going by Mtt 25:7-8. Seeing the groom' s delayed arrival, they slept with the lamp burning. It was only when they trimmed the wick did they realise that their lamps were going out for want of oil.

Comment: Trimming of the wick is done after the lamp has burned for some time. The upper end of the wick becomes hard carbon and stops absorbing oil through capillary force. Hence the need for trimming.

Comment: The text says precisely - they brought no oil. It is, to my  mind, a common (and traditional) fallacy to suppose any oil at all. These virgins were _foolish_. Very foolish. They lit their wicks and the wicks sputtered out. Because they had brought no oil in the vessel attached to the apparatus which held the wick. But I know I shall not be believed because all the books say otherwise . . . . . . . nor shall I comment any further lest weariness set in (on one side or another).

Comment: Nigel J, when you purchase a new car, it does not come with an empty fuel tank, but contains enough fuel to enable the car teach the nearest fuel station. The portable lamps made of clay or brass in Jesus'' time had a fuel tank for the oil. If the lamp did not burn at all there would be no need to trim the wick ( Mtt 25:7 ). .The wick mostly made of linen, would smoke rather than burn without oil. Moreover, with no matchbox available on those days, the virgins might have left their home for the reception with lighted lamps .

Comment: And Jesus says : They took no oil WITH THEM. If he meant they had taken empty lamps, the Lord would have said so. Connect that with the cautious behaviour of the wise virgins who took extra oil with them in a separate bottle. You can never underestimate the master story teller !

Comment: This is not a Catholic answer, so I will put it as a comment. I would consider the five wise virgins to be five periods of church history where the laity have been well trained for service and the church is healthy. The foolish virgins are five ages when the laity have not been well prepared.

Comment: The way I have heard this passage interpreted is that the oil represents a person's faith in God. So, the five virgins who had extra oil represent five people who had a large quality of faith in them for God, so it is their deep reservoir of faith in God that gets them into Heaven. The five virgins who had no extra oil represents five people whose faith in God had dried up and since they lacked faith in God, they were denied entry into Heaven.

Answer (score 2):

[St. Thomas Aquinas's commentary on Matthew](https://isidore.co/calibre/#panel=book_details&book_id=5049) ch. 25 gives three reasons for why there were 10 virgins. His 3<sup>rd</sup> reason is:

> Or He says ten on account of the number of the five senses doubled. For they are doubled in one way, according to Gregory, in that five are in men and five are in women: and so there are ten. According to Jerome, they are doubled according to the fact that they refer to the different senses: for certain senses are interior and others are exterior.